# $\pi$ Molecular orbital diagram of compounds like urea, guanidine, acetone etc

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory

In my organic chemistry course, we've only been taught about how the $\pi$ MO diagrams of compounds like butan-1,3 diene, hexan-1,3,5 triene and similar single chain compounds look like. I was wondering how the $\pi$ MO diagrams of heteroatomic compounds like urea, guanidine etc. look like, but unfortunately I was unable to find any relevant stuff in google as well as Organic textbooks like Clayden, Solomons etc.

Comment: Pretty much the same as in a physics class we learn statics but not to build a bridge

Comment: Sure, lol but @Alchimista , can you suggest any resources for the same ?

Comment: well I suggest to follow the curriculum and learn the concepts for "simple" molecules bcz they are useful. Note that you are thought systems with no etheroatoms whose chemistry is dominated by the pi electrons. I have no idea how to address you for self learning but perhaps other users can. Note that one molecule you have listed does not really exist ;)